# Fancybox Inline content Modal Window Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, programming-languages, fancybox

I'm very experienced with Fancybox, great plugin, but I can't get it to display my inline content.

According to the documentation you are supposed to use a div with style="display:none"... I've got that and I know the plugin is working, verified that all scripts are loaded and also the Fancybox overlay works when clicking the link, but the content does not show :(

```
<div style="display:none">
<div id="#apply_now">
    Content
</div>    
</div>
```

Any debug suggestions.  You can see this in the "Apply Now" links on the bottom of http://newarkcowork.com

Comment: Fancybox looks good, but lacks some of the better API functions of others *</rant>*.

Comment: What would you use alex?

Comment: Fancybox is fine, but you can't call it from code or explicitly hand it a list of images. You need to build hidden DOM elements and call events on them. Not exactly clean. For most uses of it though, it is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi as i have been there is error with

```
**[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function**
```

hance script stop to perform after on wards

Solution:

1. update all your script version
2. it may be conflicting somewhere
3. **google it**